# Wordpress custom permalink for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have 2 custom post types photos and videos
I have 3 pages news, photos, videos
In news page the posts are displayed with this permalink structure

```
/news/%category%/%postname%
```

Now for photos and videos I need some permalink structure like this

```
/photos/%category%/%postname%
/videos/%category%/%postname%
```

Finally some permalink structure like the following will work for me I guess

```
/%posttype%/%category%/%postname%
```

Is there any good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The following article might help in this regard.

http://xplus3.net/2010/05/20/wp3-custom-post-type-permalinks/

good luck.